# How do I implement SSL in Delphi to connect to a REDCap API server?

Tags: api, delphi, https, delphi-xe7, redcap

I am trying to use XE7 to connect to an in-house REDCap server. REDCap has a detailed description of the API at https://education.arcus.chop.edu/redcap-api/ and a test server at https://bbmc.ouhsc.edu/redcap/api  with a test token key.  There is assistance at https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2015-08-18/web/packages/REDCapR/vignettes/TroubleshootingApiCalls.html in R.

I can connect to the test site with Curl and PostMan. My problem is how to implement this in Delphi with SSL.

The Curl script from PostMan:

```
curl --location 'https://bbmc.ouhsc.edu/redcap/api/' \
--data-urlencode 'token=9A81268476645C4E5F03428B8AC3AA7B' \
--data-urlencode 'content=record' \
--data-urlencode 'action=export' \
--data-urlencode 'format=csv' \
--data-urlencode 'rawOrLabel=label'
```

After much searching, this is my Delphi code. What have I missed? `IdLogFile1` is a component on the form.

```pascal
function TForm1.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
begin
   showmessage('at  IOhandler');                      
     Result := true;                             // always returns true
end;


procedure TForm1.idHTTP2BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var post      : string;
    Params    : TStringList;
    idHTTP    : TIdHTTP;
    SSL1      : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    status    : integer;
    response : TstringStream;
begin
   params   := TStringList.Create;
   idHTTP   := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   SSL1     := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idHTTP);
   response  := TstringStream.create;


   SSL1.SSLOptions.Mode        := sslmClient ;
   SSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2 ];// [  sslvSSLv3,  sslvSSLv23,sslvSSLv2, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
   SSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
   SSL1.OnVerifyPeer           := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer;
   SSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode  := [ ];
   idHTTP.IOHandler            := SSL1;

   memo1.Lines.clear;

   idHTTP.ReadTimeout                 := 3000;
   idHTTP.ConnectTimeout              := 3000;
   idHttp.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;

   try

     idHTTP.HandleRedirects := true;
     idHTTP.Intercept       := IdLogFile1;
     IdLogFile1.Active      := true;

     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;

 
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['token']          := '9A81268476645C4E5F03428B8AC3AA7B';
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['content']        := 'record';
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['action']         := 'export';
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['format']         := 'csv';
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['rawOrLabel']     := 'label';
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['verify_ssl']     := 'false';
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['ssl_verify']     := 'false'; //various verify options ?
     IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['ssl_verifypeer'] := 'false';

 
     idHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
     IdHTTP.Request.Charset     := 'utf-8';
     idHTTP.HTTPOptions         := [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoForceEncodeParams];

     idHTTP.Post('https://bbmc.ouhsc.edu/redcap/api/', params, response );


   finally
        memo1.Lines.add(' ');
        memo1.lines.add(idHTTP.ResponseText);
        memo1.Lines.add(' ');
        status           := idHTTP.ResponseCode;
        memo1.Lines.Add('code: ' + inttostr(status));
 
        idhttp.Disconnect;
 
   end;
   Params.Free;
   SSL1.Free;
   idHTTP.Free;
   response.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Do you have the OpenSSL DLL's (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) with your EXE? https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Securing_Indy_Network_Connections

Comment: Used latest version   u  of the dll's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up the TLS connection correctly (provided the *appropriate* OpenSSL DLLs are available where Indy can find them).

What you are not setting up correctly is your data parameters. Curl's `--data-urlencode` command puts the data in the HTTP request body, not in the HTTP headers. So you need to put the data in the `TStringList` that you are posting (`TIdHTTP` will handle the url-encoding for you).

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.idHTTP2BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  params    : TStringList;
  idHTTP    : TIdHTTP;
  idSSL     : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  status    : integer;
  response  : string;
begin
  params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    idHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      idSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idHTTP);    

      idSSL.SSLOptions.Mode        := sslmClient ;
      idSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2 ];
      idSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      idSSL.OnVerifyPeer           := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer;
      idSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode  := [ ];
      idHTTP.IOHandler := idSSL;

      Memo1.Lines.Clear;

      idHTTP.ReadTimeout                 := 3000;
      idHTTP.ConnectTimeout              := 3000;
      idHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;

      try    
        idHTTP.HandleRedirects := true;
        idHTTP.Intercept       := IdLogFile1;
        IdLogFile1.Active      := true;

        params.Add('token=9A81268476645C4E5F03428B8AC3AA7B');
        params.Add('content=record');
        params.Add('action=export');
        params.Add('format=csv');
        params.Add('rawOrLabel=label');

        idHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        idHTTP.Request.Charset     := 'utf-8';
        idHTTP.HTTPOptions         := [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoForceEncodeParams];

        response := idHTTP.Post('https://bbmc.ouhsc.edu/redcap/api/', params);    
      finally
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
        Memo1.Lines.Add(idHTTP.ResponseText);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
        status := idHTTP.ResponseCode;
        Memo1.Lines.Add('code: ' + IntToStr(status));
      end;
    finally
      idHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy works a treat. I have spent a long time puzzling over this.

Answer (score 0):

Two simpler alternatives with System.Net.HttpClient and [mORMot](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html) . Both work as expected with same results. Tested with Delphi 11.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Net.HttpClient,
  Syncommons,
  Syncrtsock;

var
  http : TWinHttp;
  ResHeader,ResData : SockString;
  Status : cardinal;

  Client: THTTPClient;
  Response: IHTTPResponse;
  params : TStringList;
begin
    /// mORMot alternative
    http := TWinHttp.Create('bbmc.ouhsc.edu','443',true);
    try

      Status := http.Request('/redcap/api/',
                             'POST'
                             ,0,
                             'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                             'token=9A81268476645C4E5F03428B8AC3AA7B&content=record&action=export&format=csv&rawOrLabel=label',
                             '',
                             ResHeader,
                             ResData);
    finally
      http.Free;
    end;
    writeln(formatUTF8('mORMot -> Status= % Response=%',[Status , resdata ]));

    /// HttpClient alternative
    Client := THTTPClient.Create();
    try
      params := TStringList.Create;
      try
        params.Add('token=9A81268476645C4E5F03428B8AC3AA7B');
        params.Add('content=record');
        params.Add('action=export');
        params.Add('format=csv');
        params.Add('rawOrLabel=label');
        Client.CustHeaders.Add('Content-Type' , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        Response := Client.Post('https://bbmc.ouhsc.edu/redcap/api/', params);
        writeln(formatUTF8('HttpClient -> Status= % Response=%',[Response.StatusCode, Response.ContentAsString]));

        Assert(Resdata = Response.ContentAsString); // checked!
      finally
        params.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Client.Free;
    end;
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you Xalo . I am using XE7 as we have not gone to XE11 yet.

Comment: @MrGee that kind of information should be given up front.

Comment: @MrGee you are welcome. You can use mORMot option provided from Delphi 7 to Delphi 11 if you need an alternative.